# Bucardo - without Primary Key and Unique Key

Tags: postgresql, replication, bucardo

I read this from Postgresql Wiki page.

Cannot incrementally replicate tables without a unique key (it can "fullcopy" them)

1. Now we have 5.5.0, so still do we need PK or unique key for this?
2. What are the impacts of bucardo without Pk/Unique keys?

Comment: Why do you even need that? What's the purpose of a table without any unique constraint?

Comment: It's an old database infra. I'm going to migrate it to a new server, and later we'll optimise the tables

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question to Bucardo team, see the answer below.

> Yes, this is still a requirement, and will continue to be in the
>   future; you  have to be able to identify the specific rows that are
>   being  modified/replicated.